# Dynamically Create Droppable Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm implementing drag and drop using the jQuery UI [Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) widgets. (Sortable didn't provide quite enough flexibility for me.)

As I drag, I'm dynamically creating a drop placeholder element to show precisely where a drop would be placed.

But how can I make this drop placeholder droppable itself? If I create it and then immediately call the `droppable()` method on it, this has no effect. And so if they user drops directly over a drop placeholder, how could I detect this?

You can see what I have so far at http://jsbin.com/uciviy/14.

Comment: Have you thought of making the switch to HTML5 and utilize it's [Drag and Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

Comment: Yes, but I haven't thought of a way to force all my users to upgrade to HTML5-compatible browsers.

Comment: Ah yes, the age-old conundrum. Would you mind sharing some code? Might spark an idea.

Comment: a demo in jsfiddle.net would help. Objective isn't entirely clear

Comment: You should be able to make something droppable dynamically. Have a look at this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/28RVN/3/

Comment: Sorry for the delay (been out snowshoeing). I've added a link to my jsbin project.

Comment: @mccannf: Since you took the trouble to create a jsfiddle, repost as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to create a div dynamically and make it droppable.

You can either create the div through JQuery and then make it droppable, or create a droppable div when the drag event begins on a draggable element and that element can be dropped on the new div created. This is possible like so:

```
$( "<div>Dynamic Droppable Div</div>" ).droppable( dropOptions ).appendTo( "#anotherDiv" );
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/28RVN/3/).

Comment: i fetch error : "dropOptions undefined " ..plz help me

Comment: i have use after  : $("#" + appendID).after(NewDropPanelv).droppable();